# Apache Flink : Handle bad avro records in confluent-avro from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I've created a table using Flink's table APIs.

```
CREATE TABLE recommendations (
 ...

) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'my_kafka_topic',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
  'properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name' = 'kafka',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://schema-registry-address',
  'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY'
);
```

When running the SQL to view the records, I'm getting:

```
Flink SQL> select * from default_catalog.default_database.recommendations ;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -25

Flink SQL> select * from default_catalog.default_database.recommendations ;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
```

I'm aware there are some BAD avro records being pushed into the Kafka topic. In JSON format, there's an option to skip/filter these records by setting
 `'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'`. **Is there any way we can skip these records when reading from confluent-avro format?**

It's not ideal but unfortunately, I can't control what's being pushed to Kafka despite having a schema registry.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no such option for AVRO. There's an open ticket for it at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20091